# jQuery right side popup not working with contact form! anyone have solution for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

side slide popup only accepting paragraph content. and I want to add a contact form to it. fiddle - [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/pw43te5k/11/)

a working example is here - https://grapyhost.com/tstt/

```
$(function() {

  // from right to left
  $('#test2').PopupLayer({
    to: 'left',
    blur: true,
    content: "<p class='dmpopup'>fdgdfgdfgdfg</p>",
    color: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: "#222",
  });


});
```

Comment: https://www.formget.com/jquery-popup-form/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal to accomplish your task.

Code here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <h1 class="text-center"><a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</a></h1><!-- This is the button that will show the contact form-->

  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><!-- This is the contact form that will be displayed-->
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">We'd Love to Hear From You</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group"><label>Name</label><input class="form-control required" placeholder="Your name" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be at least 3 characters long, and must only contain letters." type="text"></div>
          <div class="form-group"><label>Message</label><textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here.." data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual"></textarea></div>
          <div class="form-group"><label>E-Mail</label><input class="form-control email" placeholder="email@you.com (so that we can contact you)" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid e-mail address (user@gmail.com)" type="text"></div>
          <div class="form-group"><label>Phone</label><input class="form-control phone" placeholder="999-999-9999" data-placement="top" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Must be a valid phone number (999-999-9999)" type="text"></div>
          <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send It!</button> <p class="help-block pull-left text-danger hide" id="form-error">&nbsp; The form is not valid. </p></div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkk9qgud/)